# what happens when reduceByKey in action?

Tags: apache-spark

My *mapToPair* function produces the output below.

(a, 1)
(a, 1)
(b, 1)

I'm reducing the values using reduceByKey function and the code follows:

```
  private static final Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> WORDS_REDUCER =
      new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        public Integer call(Integer a, Integer b) throws Exception {
          return a + b;
        }
      };
```

It is working fine, can someone explains me how this code works when performing for the pair (b, 1) ?

Comment: If you are using spark with java, use lambda rather than functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite clear from the question what it is that you don't understand, but perhaps this will help...

reduceByKey with the function x+y acts as an accumulator, summing the values per key. If you only have one value for a particular key, that value will be the summed result.

Here's an example using PySpark:

```
  testrdd = sc.parallelize((('a', 1), ('a', 1), ('b', 1)))
  testrdd = testrdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
  result = testrdd.collect()
  print ("result: {}".format(result))

  >result: [('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have one more question.

Comment: Thanks. your answer helps me..I have one more question.
can you also advise me how can I reduce (using reduceByKey) the RDD below. It has key as String and values are Iterable of Touple class (Touple is user defined class).

JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Touple>> group = pairs.groupByKey();

Comment: @sras, you should open a new question for your new question. Take care to explain the question in as much detail as you can - it is not very clear from your comment.